# What permanent grasses should I look into?

Tags: grass, domestic-animals

I'm looking for a drought tolerant fast growing grass mix that will work well with chickens in USDA zone 4A. What should I mix together for USDA zone 4a for feeding my chickens for planting it once?

Comment: I think you should give more information: type of ground (acidity, heavy, sand, rocks, rich of organic materials), shadows, orientation, water (dry, humid (near some river), do water accumulate on heavy rains? )

Comment: Dry prairie on rolling hills I will be getting some machinery in to slow water runoff down.